# How to make a really compact getDigit() method

Tags: java

I am working on a project where I need to make a really compact getDigit method.

For example I would enter:
`getDigit(1234, 4)` and I would get back `1`

Thanks!

Comment: Where is your code? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What do you mean by "really compact", and what was wrong with the code that you tried yourself, before posting here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method:

```
public static int getDigit(int number, int k)
{
    return (number / (int)Math.pow(10, k - 1)) % 10;
}
```

Comment: What, if any, are the limitations on `k`?  What inputs will this work for, and what will it fail for?

Comment: Good question, `k` must be >= 1 and after k exceeds the number of digits in the `number` it will return 0

Comment: and more importantly, `k` must also be `<= 10`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way to do it in one line:

`return (number%(int)Math.pow(10, k+1))/((int)Math.pow(10, k));`